# Import sheets from folder into master, optimize code to avoid runtime error row by row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There is a code here that loads data from spreadsheets in one folder into a master sheet. Then it does a check and pushes values to the folder sheets so that there are no duplicates being sent over.

The issue I experience is that I am having to do this with over 50k values, and may often run into runtime errors.

How should this be modified to avoid going row by row?

```
  function getDataToMaster() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("111p5daTNJkyDL5vf0TmiKuqtQBjz8ryL"); //Define id of folder
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file; 
  var data;
  var sheetMaster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  while(contents.hasNext()){  
    file = contents.next();
    if (file.getMimeType() == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet") {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
      var startRow = 2; 
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var colToCheck = 6;
      for(var j = 1; j < data.length;j++){
        if(data[j][colToCheck-1] != "copied"){
          sheetMaster.appendRow(data[j]);
          sheet.getRange((j+1), colToCheck).setValue("copied");
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to reduce the process cost for putting values to Spreadsheet.
- You want to improve the following part.

  ```
  for(var j = 1; j < data.length;j++){
    if(data[j][colToCheck-1] != "copied"){
      sheetMaster.appendRow(data[j]);
      sheet.getRange((j+1), colToCheck).setValue("copied");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification point:

- In order to reduce the process cost of above part, I propose to use `setValues` instead of `appendRow` and `setValue`. Ref

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

From:

```
for(var j = 1; j < data.length;j++){
  if(data[j][colToCheck-1] != "copied"){
    sheetMaster.appendRow(data[j]);
    sheet.getRange((j+1), colToCheck).setValue("copied");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

To:

```
var copiedValues = [];
var putValues = [];
for(var j = 1; j < data.length;j++){
  if(data[j][colToCheck-1] != "copied"){
    putValues.push(data[j]);
  }
  copiedValues.push(["copied"]);
}
if (putValues.length > 0) {  // Added
  sheet.getRange(2, colToCheck, copiedValues.length, copiedValues[0].length).setValue(copiedValues);
  sheetMaster.getRange(sheetMaster.getLastRow() + 1, 1, putValues.length, putValues[0].length).setValues(putValues);
}
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Benchmark: Reading and Writing Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)

I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet. So if I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (line 24, file "Code")

Clarifying that it works just fine, but I do get the error above.

Comment: @Roasted Carrot Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. But I would like to resolve your issue. So in order to replicate your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: In addition I noticed that there is a delay when running multiple times. I ran this about 5 times in a row 2 minutes apart, adding new sheets of data, and it seems to import sporadically.

Comment: @Roasted Carrot Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, you said an error occurs. But in your latest replying, you say `I noticed that there is a delay when running multiple times. I ran this about 5 times in a row 2 minutes apart, adding new sheets of data, and it seems to import sporadically.`. In this case, the script worked? I cannot understand about your current situation. Can you explain about the detail information of your current situation?

Comment: @Roasted Carrot And also, about `I noticed that there is a delay when running multiple times. I ran this about 5 times in a row 2 minutes apart, adding new sheets of data, and it seems to import sporadically.`, this specification cannot be found in your question. So can you update your question by including the detail information of your situation?

Comment: In this folder are located the example sheets: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1usuQBjeEQozK8wU63jZo0bxmqP_aXrll

Here is the example Source sheet of where all the files are dumped: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I06sKh-g8KFp-topBLl7ezBqdWW4rt7OmB55CJpepXw/edit?usp=sharing

The last file, CouponSheet5 has not been copied over yet. Once you run the script, the error message **TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 24, file "Code")** shows.

The script works just fine, it just throws an error.

Comment: @Roasted Carrot Thank you for replying and adding the information. From the information, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?